# Here, I am trying to login using firebase auth, but getting 400 error. I am giving exact email & password but it's showing below error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, localhost, react-devtools

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-email).
at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:122:1)
at _fail (assert.ts:65:1)
at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:171:1)
at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:189:1)
at async _signInWithCredential (credential.ts:37:1) '\n    at Login
```

(http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:339:76)\n    at Routes
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75188:5)\n    at div\n    at App\n    at Router
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75121:15)\n    at BrowserRouter
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73930:5)'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-email).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:122:1)
    at _fail (assert.ts:65:1)
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:171:1)
    at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:189:1)
    at async _signInWithCredential (credential.ts:37:1) '\n    at Login (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:339:76)\n    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75188:5)\n    at div\n    at App\n    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75121:15)\n    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73930:5)'

Comment: Using onBlur={event => setPassword(event.target.value)} on each input field did help. The main problem was it couldn't get the value from the input field earlier. 400 problem occurs if it can't get proper value which makes it a bad request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you are getting the value from the input correctly. use console.log(#) to check for value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).